# Want to create a database that can automatically regenerate when new info comes in

Tags: database

This is my first question on this site. Can anyone tell me how I can or if I can create a database that will pull in data from a number of excel spreadsheets, combine them and create a database whenever a product number, price or other change takes place. I also need to have pictures added to correspond to each product.